# String must be exactly one character long

Tags: c#

I have what I think is an easy problem. For some reason the following code generates the exception, "String must be exactly one character long".

```
int n = 0;
foreach (char letter in charMsg)
{
    // Get the integral value of the character.
    int value = Convert.ToInt32(letter);
    // Convert the decimal value to a hexadecimal value in string form.
    string hexOutput = String.Format("{0:X}", value);
    //Console.WriteLine("Hexadecimal value of {0} is {1}", letter, hexOutput);
    charMsg[n] = Convert.ToChar(hexOutput);
    n++;
}
```

The exception occurs at the `charMsg[n] = Convert.ToChar(hexOutput);` line. Why does it happen? When I check the values of `CharMsg` it seems to contain all of them properly, yet still throws an error at me.

**UPDATE:** I've solved this problem, it was my mistake. Sorry for bothering you.

OK, this was a really stupid mistake on my part. Point is, with my problem I'm not even supposed to do this as hex values clearly won't help me in any way.

What I am trying to do it to encrypt a message in an image. I've already encrypted the length of said message in last digits on each color channel of first pixel. Now I'm trying to put the very message in there. I lookt here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII and said to myself without thinking that usung hexes would be a good idea. Can't belive I thought that.

Comment: What does this have to do with linq?

Comment: Instead of Convert.ToChar(hexOutput), use Convert.ToChar(value)

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: Obviously hexOutput is more than one character long.  What are you trying to do? (add to your question, not in another comment)

Comment: My input string comes ftom a textbox.

Comment: Please add a sample input and the expected output to your question.  It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Since printable unicode characters can be anywhere in range from `0x0000` to `0xFFFF`, your hexOutput variable can hold more than one character - this is why error is thrown. 
`Convert.ToChar(string)` would always check length a of string, and if it is not equal to 1 - it would throw. So it would not convert string `0x30` to hexadecimal number, and then to ascii representation, symbol `0`.

Can you elaborate on what you are trying to archieve ?

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToChar( string s )`, [per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3ew98y.aspx) requires a single character string, otherwise it throws a `FormatException` as you've noted. It is a rough, though more restrictive, equivalent of

public char string2char( string s )
  {
    return s[0] ;
  }

Your code does the following:

- Iterates over all the characters in some enumrable collection of characters.
- For each such character, it...

  - Converts the char to an int. *Hint:* a `char` is an integral type: its an unsigned 16-bit integral value.
  - converts that value to a string containing a hex representation of the character in question. For most characters, that string will be at least two character in length: for instance, converting the space character (' ', 0x20) this way will give you the string "20".
  - You then try to convert that back to a char and replace the current item being iterated over. This is where your exception is thrown. One thing you should note here is that altering a collection being enumerated is likely to cause the enumerator to throw an exception.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish here. For instance, given a `charMsg` that consist of 3 characters, 'a', 'b' and 'c', what should happen. A clear problem statement helps us to help you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help me. I've updated OP, and as you can see i've made a really stupid mistake in even thinking about using hexes the way I wanted to. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your hexOutput is a string, and I'm assuming charMsg is a character array. Suppose the first element in charMsg is 'p', or hex value 70. The documentation for Convert.ToChar(string) says it'll use just the first character of the string ('7'), but it's wrong. It'll throw this error. You can test this with a static example, like `charMsg[n] = Convert.ToChar("70");`. You'll get the same error.

Are you trying to replace characters with hex values? If so, you might try using a StringBuilder object instead of your array assignments.

Answer (score -1):

Convert.ToChar(string) if it is empty string lead this error. instead use cchar()